# Android Emulator force close for localhost

Tags: android, mysql

My app is getting error force close, when i am trying to connect MySQL server (via xampp), please help me.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String result =null;
        InputStream is=null;
        StringBuilder sb =null;

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http:/localhost/db.php");
            List<? extends NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null;
            httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response =httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();
            is=entity.getContent();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in httpconnection"+e.toString());
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
             sb = new StringBuilder();
             sb.append(reader.readLine()+ "\n");
             String line ="0";
             while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                 sb.append(line +"\n");
             }
             is.close();
             result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+ e.toString());
        }
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String refno,name;
            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data=null;

                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
                    refno =json_data.getString("refno");
                    name = json_data.getString("name");
                }
            }catch(JSONException e1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch(ParseException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();

                }

        }

}
```

Comment: Where is this code running? Emulator or Device? Where is the server runnng? What is the error exactly?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: You are running this code on the main ui thread. That will cause for an NetworkOnMainThreadException. Put your code in an AsyncTask or thread. Care for internet permission in manifest. You cannot call 'localhost'. What you have to call depends on your setup. WHERE DOES YOUR SERVER RUN?

Comment: Yeah my php code gets connected to MySQl

Comment: That is an irrelevant remark. As soon as you comment on all my remarks and answered my questions i will continue.

Comment: Hi server running on same system